# Efficiently get a list of booleans that correlates to wheter an item exists in a list of dictionaries, using panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I wish to add a boolean/binary 'CONDITION' column to my existing data frame based on whether a predefined value exists in the given row's 'DICTIONARY' column that contains a dictionary of simple string-string pairs, and we are looking at its keys. I tried to avoid writing my own loop with:

```
df.loc['KEYWORD' in df['DICTIONARY'], 'CONDITION'] = 1
df.loc['KEYWORD' not in df['DICTIONARY'], 'CONDITION'] = 0
```

But it gives the error:

```
KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'
```

The same error showed up when I've tried:

```
condition = ('KEYWORD' in (i for i in df['DICTIONARY']))
df.loc[condition, 'CONDITION'] = 1
```

I have also tried with this, however it results in a generator which I was unable to utilize:

```
condition = ('KEYWORD' in i for i in df['DICTIONARY'].tolist())
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample to question?

Comment: There are dictionaries, so best `print (df['DICTIONARY'].head(5).to_dict())`

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is large and confidential. I can only describe it, if it needs more clarification:

The data frame in question contains a list of entities, for which there is a 'DICTIONARY' value for each, describing name and (purely numeric) ID pairs, read as strings from csv, to a dictionary form for easier searching. The relevant keywords are present in the keys of these dictionaries, so when a keyword is entered, the associated rows can be highlighted by the 'CONDITION' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible convert valuest to strings and then test subtrings use:

```
df['CONDITION'] = df['DICTIONARY'].astype(str).str.contains('KEYWORD').astype(int)
```

---

```
df['CONDITION'] = np.where(df['DICTIONARY'].astype(str).str.contains('KEYWORD'), 1, 0)
```

Or maybe (depends of data):

```
df['CONDITION'] = df['DICTIONARY'].map(lambda x: 'KEYWORD' in x).astype(int)

df['CONDITION'] = np.where(df['DICTIONARY'].map(lambda x: 'KEYWORD' in x), 1, 0)
```

Comment: The first two solution works perfectly!
However the second two drops
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable